# SQL/SQLite/SQLite studio: Get strings composed from at least two words

Tags: sql, regex, database, sqlite

Is there a way to get strings composed from at least 2 words?

My idea is to get strings with minimum length 10 (for example).
Or there is another way - get values which contain at least one space.

Is it possible to implement one of these solutions using SQLite query?
REGEXP does not work. I tried this `SELECT english FROM translations WHERE english REGEXP '* *';`

Thanks

Comment: This `^(?=.{10,}$).*` would match strings with min 10 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `like` for this:

```
SELECT english
FROM translations
WHERE english like '% %'
```

Comment: Won't this give false positives for ' ', ' word' and such?

Comment: @popovitsj: you could trim the value before comparison in order to get rid of leading or trailing blanks